# turtlesim cannot work

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone,

I am new in ROS, and i am following the manual on ros.org.
I hanv just successfully installed turtlesim package, but i can not find the turtlesim_node. I download one but it does work. It says:

/opt/ros/electric/ros/turtlesim/turtlesim_node: error while loading shared libraries: librosstack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Can anyone tell me what the preblem is ? Hope to receive your help. Thanks a lot.

Yours,
Kevin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39079/turtlesim-cannot-work/) by [kevinxhj](https://answers.ros.org/users/2849/kevinxhj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Kevin,

Sorry if you've already done this, but let's start with the basics. Please confirm that you have set up your bash environment correctly. Can you echo your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and confirm it is correct?

Check this link http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment.

If anything there is not working, go back a step and confirm that you've done everything at this page correctly http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) with karma: 342 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0